# A strange consequence of Isotropy in Phase Space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry, phase-space, gas

In *Goodstein, States of Matter, page 66* the following is stated:

> For a single particle the number of states in a region $d^3pd^3r$ of its phase space is:
> $$\frac{d^3pd^3r}{(2 \pi \hbar)^2} \tag{1.3.101}$$
> For the perfect gas nothing depends on $r$, so the coordinate of integration can be extracted as the volume $V$, furthermore the problem is isotropic, so that
> $$d^3p=4\pi p^2 dp \tag{1.3.102}$$

Now: I have no problem with (1.3.101), it is simply the volume of our portion of phase space divided by the volume that a state occupies; this is of course equal to the number of states in that portion, perfect. I am also completely fine with the statement about extracting the volume $V$, no problem.

My problem regards the next statement: the fact that isotropy implies (1.3.102), why is that? *Goodstein* doesn't show any proof for (1.3.102), it simply states that it must be true if we have isotropy; but why? $d^3p$ simply means $dp_xdp_ydp_z$, why should it be equal to that?

(1.3.102) reminds me of the formula for the volume of a sphere, but I don't get the link with isotropy. Furthermore isotropy doesnt't mean spherical simmetry, and also the perfect gas is contained in a square box, and the little cells of phase space have also the shape of a box, no sphere anywhere.

How can we prove that isotropy implies (1.3.102)? What is the logic behind this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isotropy means that the function being integrated depends only on the combination $p = \sqrt{ p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2}$, but not independently on $p_x$, $p_y$ or $p_z$. We therefore have an integral of the form
$$
\int d^3 p f(p) 
$$
We now simplify $d^3p$ by working in spherical coordinates where
$$
d^3 p =  p^2 \sin\theta dp d\theta d\phi , \qquad \vec{p} = ( p \sin \theta \cos \phi , p \sin \theta \sin \phi , p \cos \theta ) .
$$
But now due to the assumption of isotropy, $f(p)$ does not depend on $\theta$ or $\phi$ so we can perform those integrals explicitly,
$$
\int d^3 p f(p)  = \int dp d\theta d\phi p^2 \sin\theta  f(p) = 4\pi \int dp p^2 f(p)
$$
or in other words $d^3 p = 4 \pi p^2 dp$.

PS - Isotropy does mean spherical symmetry. The very first line on the Wiki article provides a definition: "Isotropy is uniformity in all orientations" which is another way of saying spherically symmetric.

Comment: Wonderful answer! Thanks a lot. But I would suggest switching $d^3p$ and $f(p)$ in the integrals for ease of reading. Written in this current way it can seem that $d^3pf(p)$ is the whole differential instead of $\int f(p)d^3p$, which is the correct interpretation.

Comment: Physicists put $dp$ _before_ the function being integrated so I find it easy to read as is.